# SVC Classifier with 0% accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using SVC from Sklearn to discriminate between different matrices.
The datas are 95 matrices of correlation, computed from IRM of patients with schizophrenia (50 matrices) and healty controls (45 matrices). They are pretty big (264*264), so I wasn't expecting perfect results, but 0% accuracy seems really low.

**Datas:** 95 matrices 264*264, values in [-1,1]

### Code

Here is the code:

```
## Datas
#control_matrices: list of 45 matrices
#patient_matrices: list of 50 matrices

n_training = 25 #Number of matrices of control to train SVC (25 control and 25 patient)
indices = np.triu_indices(264,1) #Since the matrices are symetric, I just take the upper triangle

perm_control = np.random.permutation(45) #Doing a permutation to take random matrices for training
contr_matrices = control_matrices[perm_control] #control_matrices is a list of matrices
perm_patient = np.random.permutation(50) #Same with the patient matrices
pat_matrices = patient_matrices[perm_patient] 

x_control = [m[indices] for m in contr_matrices[:n_training]] #Data for training
x_patient = [m[indices] for m in pat_matrices[:n_training]]

test_control = [m[indices] for m in contr_matrices[n_training:]] #Data for test once the SVM is trained
test_patient = [m[indices] for m in pat_matrices[n_training:]]

X = np.concatenate((x_control, x_patient))
Y = np.asarray( n_training*[0] + n_training*[1] ) #Control: 0 - Patient: 1


perm = np.random.permutation(50)
X = X[perm]
Y = Y[perm]

## Training

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X,Y)
```

### Expected Results

Since the size of the data is huge compared to the number of matrices, I would have expected low results (something just a little bit better than 50%).

### Actual Results

```
clf.score(np.concatenate((test_control, test_patient)), 20*[0]+25*[1])

>>> 0.0
```

The same happens whenever I run the code (so, with different permutations), and for `n_training` from 10 to 45.  However the SVC does remember well the first matrices, for the training (`clf.score(X,Y)` is  `1.0`).

### Other Try

The same goes for `clf=LinearSVC()` and `clf=LogisticRegression()`.

I also tried this, with exactly the same results:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score
from nilearn import connectome

connectivity_coefs = connectome.sym_to_vec(matrices, ConnectivityMeasure) 
# This turns the matrices to a list of vectors

Y = 45*[0] + 50*[1]

cv = StratifiedKFold(Y, n_folds=3, shuffle=True)
svc = LinearSVC()

cv_scores = cross_val_score(svc, connectivity_coefs, Y, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy')

print('Score: %1.2f +- %1.2f' % (cv_scores.mean(), cv_scores.std()))

>>> Score: 0.00 +- 0.00
```

I also tried with simpler data : matrices `[0]` for Control and `[1]` for Patients. The SVC worked perfectly, so first I suspected it has something to do with the size of the matrices I use (huge size and few samples).

But with `matrices = np.random.rand(95,264,264)`, I get `Score: 0.58 +- 0.03`.

And with the complete matrices instead of juste the upper triangle, I still get 0% accuracy.

I completely fail to understand what is happening here.

### Versions

```
Windows-8-6.2.9200
Python 3.4.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 19 2014, 13:02:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
NumPy 1.9.1
SciPy 0.15.1
Scikit-Learn 0.15.2
```

### Datas

Here is the complete code to get the matrices I use (IRM from an open dataset):

```
from nilearn import datasets
from nilearn import input_data
from nilearn.connectome import ConnectivityMeasure
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score
from nilearn import connectome


## Atlas for the parcellation and Dataset

power = datasets.fetch_coords_power_2011()
coords = np.vstack((power.rois['x'], power.rois['y'], power.rois['z'])).T
datas = datasets.fetch_cobre(n_subjects=None, verbose=0)

spheres_masker = input_data.NiftiSpheresMasker(
                    seeds=coords, smoothing_fwhm=4, radius=5.,
                    detrend=True, standardize=True,
                    high_pass=0.01, t_r=2, verbose=0)


## Extracting useful IRM

list_time_series = []
i = 0
for fmri_filenames, confounds_file in zip(datas.func, datas.confounds): #Might take a few minutes
    print("Sujet %s" % i)
    if i != 38 and i != 41: #Subjects removed from the study
        conf = np.genfromtxt(confounds_file)
        conf = np.delete(conf, obj = 16, axis = 1) #Remove Global Signal
        conf = np.delete(conf, obj = 0, axis = 0) #Remove labels
        scrub = [i for i in range(150) if conf[i,7]==1]    
        conf = np.delete(conf, obj = 7, axis = 1) #Remove Scrub
        if len(scrub) < 90: #Keep at least 60 non scrub
            time_series = spheres_masker.fit_transform(fmri_filenames, confounds=conf)
            time_series = np.delete(time_series, obj = scrub, axis = 0) #Remove scrub
            list_time_series.append(time_series)
        else:
            list_time_series.append([])
    else:
        list_time_series.append([])
    i+=1


## Computing correlation matrices

N = len(datas.phenotypic)
control_subjects = []
patient_subjects = []
for i in range(N):
    t = list_time_series[i]
    if type(t) != list :
        subject = datas.phenotypic[i]
        if str(subject[4])=='b\'Control\'':
            control_subjects.append(t)
        else:
            patient_subjects.append(t)
control_subjects = np.asarray(control_subjects)            
patient_subjects = np.asarray(patient_subjects)

connect_measure = ConnectivityMeasure(kind='tangent')
control_matrices=connect_measure.fit_transform(control_subjects)
patient_matrices=connect_measure.fit_transform(patient_subjects)

matrices = np.concatenate((control_matrices, patient_matrices))
```

Or you can download them [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfzw6s45knxkk1b/matrices.zip?dl=0).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you are stacking the unhealthy patients directly on top of the healthy patients? Try permuting the variable 'X' and your test set 'np.concatenate((test_control, test_patient)'

Comment: I tried adding  a permutation, still got 0% accuracy.

Comment: Did a few tests on the *code* section. With `np.random.rand(45,264,264)` and `np.random.rand(50,264,264)` got arround 50% precision (so what we could expect). Added +/-0.5, got score of `1.0` (Also what we could expect)). Did you try with the complete matrices instead of just the upper triangle?

Comment: Yes, I tried with the complete matrices, still no result.

Comment: Is it real relevance between your data and the answer y? It may be a situation when there is unable to fit (with your custom type of a classifier). For the test try your classifier when x is equal to y.

Comment: @sergzach I hope there is relevance between x and y... The matrices corresponds to real datas from control and patient. And the classifier seems to be able to recognize them, since I have 0% accuracy and not 50%.

Comment: @LBlnd If you have a lot of classes and not so much data then it could be just casual thing. Could you output x and y and attach to your question?

Comment: @sergzach I added  `control_matrices` and `patient_matrices` ; I could output some `X` and `Y` but they change everytime due to the permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `["Control"]`and`["Patient"]`as output label, you should assign output label to a number (for example `Control` as `0` and `Patient` as `1`) because ML algorithm only handles real numbers.
 So

```
Y = np.asarray( n_training*["Control"] + n_training*["Patient"] )
```

should be

```
Y = np.asarray( n_training*[0] + n_training*[1] )
```

and

```
clf.score(np.concatenate((test_control, test_patient)), 20*['Control']+25*['Patient'])
```

should be

```
clf.score(np.concatenate((test_control, test_patient)), np.asarray( 20*[0] + 25*[1] ))
```

Comment: I tried with real numbers, but I still get 0.0 accuracy :/

Comment: I tried to fit your whole dataset with same model setting and the model always predict 1 on your input.
It mean your current model setting is not good enough.
You should find another setting for the model. For SVM, you should try different values for C and gamma and take the best one.
To find the best setting for your model, you can take a look at this
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV